# undefined method `exists=' for in load_current_resource in Chef provider

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, lwrp

In writing a provider (for a Datastax Opscenter Cluster resource), I required knowledge of any currently existing cluster with the same cluster_id and so have written a `load_current_resource` method in the provider. My problem is that at run time (as a chef-solo run on a Vagrant instance) I receive an error:

```
undefined method `exists=' for Chef::Resource::OpscenterCluster
```

On the `@current_resource.exists = false` after `if response.code != 200` in the method below.

```
def load_current_resource
   @current_resource = Chef::Resource::OpscenterCluster.new(@new_resource.name)
   log "#{@new_resource} Opscenter Cluster '#{new_resource.name}'"
   @current_resource.name(@new_resource.name)
   uri = URI.parse "http://#{node[:opscenter][:ip]}:8888/cluster-configs/#{@current_resource.cluster_id}"
   response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
   if response.code != 200
      @current_resource.exists = false
   else
      @current_resource.exists = true
   end
end
```

The cookbook is `opscenter` and the resource and provider are both in files called `cluster.rb`, and the attributes that are referenced definitely exist, so the name of the resource class should at least, and the attributes at least should be correct.

Any ideas as to why my @current_resource object doesn't have an `exists=` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define it on your resource...

You can either define an `exists=(value)` method, or you can use Chef's preferred method of `.exsts(false)` (note - no =)

Comment: Ah, missed that in the tutorial. I'm not exactly sure what your solution is suggesting as code though. I added `attr_accessor :exists` to my resource, which is how [@dougireton's tutorial](http://dougireton.com/blog/2012/12/31/creating-an-lwrp/) explains how to do it in a lwrp.